# Database Table Schema Design for normal Authentication + OAuth

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, database-design, oauth-2.0

Can someone explain the pros/cons of this 2 table schema for `Authentication` + `OAuth`?

Choice 1:

User Table:

```
`id`
`unique_id`
`username`
`email`
`bio`
`gender`
```

User_open_id Table:

```
`user_id`
`open_id_type ('facebook, twitter etc')`
`open_id ('facebook_id, twitteer_id etc')`
`open_password`
```

Choice 2:

User Table:

```
`id`
`unique_id`
`username`
`email`
`bio`
`gender`
```

User_normal Table:

```
`user_id`
`user_password`
```

User_facebook Table:

```
`user_id`
`facebook_id`
`facebook_password`
```

User_google_plus Table:

```
`user_id`
`googleplus_id`
`googleplus_password`
```

User_twitter Table:

```
`user_id`
`twitter_id`
`twitter_password`
```

Will Choice 1 face any problem in the future? ( Like table structure changes for a specific service like facebook/google plus etc )

Comment: I would go for Option 1

Comment: will Choice 1 cause any problem in the future for OAuth, like change in data columns? will facebook/twitter/googleplus or other Oauth services share the same data columns like `open_id_type ('facebook, twitter etc')` and `open_id ('facebook_id, twitteer_id etc')`?

Comment: With different tables advantage is if tomorrow there is one more Authz provider you want to support you can do that by just spinning a new table and also upgrade scenarios will be easy..

Comment: I see, does that means that Choice 2 is the better schema for the future?